# Running firebase serve to use local emulators support doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-tools

I have been using Firebase with success for my projects, and I am working to improve the project by using ReactJS.

The problem is most of examples like [Getting Started with React and Firebase - Firecasts (2016)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mwNATxfUsgI) and [How to use Firebase Firestore with ReactJS (2019)](https://youtu.be/yyo_TcZCrS4) use  `npm star` to emulate a local web server.

```
npx create-react-app myReactProject
cd myReactProject
npm install firebase --save
npm install -g firebase-tools
firebase init
npm start
```

`npm start` works fine (traditional "React App" page with react logo spinning), but without function, database, storage emulators, and multi-site support that we have by using the firebase CLI tool.

The problem is, if I run `firebase serve` to use local emulators support, nothing works.

Are there specifics steps to install ReactJS and uses the firebase serve tool, both together, or the only way to use firebase serve and reactjs is by using declarative JavaScript library in HTML files?

Comment: Thanks, @frank for update the title here. Just a reminder. The issue is around the React features. If I run "npm start", react feature works fine, but when I run "firebase serve", the react features (like bundle script, substitute %PUBLIC_URL%) don't work

Comment: @MaksimIvanov replied to this issue in his channel here
[Hosting Multiple Sites With Firebase - Separate React Apps For Admin and Public Pages](https://youtu.be/2ayNDsqtjHs). Thank you very much Maksim Ivanov!